# TCSH - most compact sytax for checking if value in an array/list?

Tags: tcsh

I'm trying to find out if there's a more compact way to write the following format tcsh code, ideally still in tcsh. I spent a while searching around using different keywords but couldn't find anything helpful.

Essentially the code snippet is just looping though a number sequence, and then if that looped value is within a set of numbers, assigning a variable. For simplicity I've made the lists of numbers $VAR is being compared against relatively short, and the number of comparison occurrences few, but the actual problem is double the size is both respects.

```
foreach VAR (`seq 1 24`)
    if ($VAR == 1 || $VAR == 2 || $VAR == 3 || $VAR == 4) then 
        set cat = small
    else if ($VAR == 5 || $VAR == 6 || $VAR == 7 || $VAR == 8) then
        set cat = medium
    else
        set cat = large
    endif
end
```

I suppose I was thinking more along the lines of python where you can just say "if x in [...]" etc., rather than needing to compare $VAR to every number individually as is the case above. I'd considered the following type of setup, but one ends up with more lines overall.

```
foreach VAR (`seq 1 24`)
    foreach C (1 2 3 4)
        if ($C == $VAR) then
            set cat = small
        endif
    end
    ...
end
```

If the provided code is as simple as is gets in tcsh, is there a more succinct way in say, bash?  Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that in `tcsh` You won't save any lines thou:

```
#/bin/tcsh
foreach VAR (`seq 1 24`)
  if (${VAR} < 5) then
    set cat = "small"
  else if (${VAR} > 8) then
    set cat = "large"
  else
    set cat = "medium"
  endif
end
exit(0)
```

You can also consider passing logic to AWK (I do not know if helps in Your case):

```
#/bin/tcsh
foreach VAR (`seq 1 24`)
  set cat = (`echo ${VAR} | awk '$0<5 {print("small"); exit;} $0>8 {print("large"); exit;} {print("medium");}'`)
end
exit (0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately the problem in hand has arbitrary numbers however, where the numbers aren't typically consecutive. Thus using < and > is rarely likely to work.